# Why am I getting this runtime error on leetcode - runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h) for the code below

Tags: recursion

```
class Solution {
public:
    int fact(int n)
    {
        if(n==1||n==0)
            return 1;
        return n*fact(n-1);
    }
    void helper(int n,int k,int p,vector<int>&a)
    {  
        if(n==0||k==0)
        return;
        int h=fact(n-1);
        int index=(k/h);
            if(k%h==0)
            index=index-1;
        int l=a[index];
    
        for(int i=p;i<index;i++)
        {a[i+1]=a[i];}
        a[p]=l;
        helper(n-1,k,p+1,a); 
    }
    string getPermutation(int n, int k) {
        
        vector<int>a;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            a[i]=i+1; 
        helper(n,k,0,a);
        string s="";
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            string a=to_string(a[i]);
            s+=a;
        }
      return s;
    }
};
```